# Unset a argument variable

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I have created a script in sh shell.

```
#script.sh
echo $1

if [ x$1 = 'x' ]
then
 echo CODE1
else
 echo CODE2
fi
```

1) if I am running it using `. ./script.sh`

```
OUTPUT: CODE1
```

2) If I run it like `. ./script.sh arg1`

```
OUTPUT: arg1
CODE2
```

3)if I run it again after using `. ./script.sh`
then it gives me

```
OUTPUT: arg1
CODE2
```

I think 3rd has same output as 2nd because I am running 3rd in the same shell as 2nd so $1 is not deallocated and 3rd is actully using the value of $1 set by 2nd.

But if I deallocate it using unset 1 then shell is giving error as unknown identifire.

How can I deallocate this environment variable $1 ?
OR
How can I set it to null.

Answer (score 0):

By sourcing your shell with `.`, you're running it in the context of your current shell.  If you just don't do that, none of these problems will happen:

```
$ ./script.sh 

CODE1
$ ./script.sh arg1
arg1
CODE2
$ ./script.sh

CODE1
```

Comment: You are right Carl. But I want to run the script in the current shell.
That is why I want to deallocate the variable.

Comment: Hm, ok.  I don't see the behaviour you do, though.  What shell do you use that's behaving this way?